# ekf_localization_node: what frame for IMU?

Tags: ros, imu, ekf, frame, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I am trying to fuse GPS with IMU information with ekf_localization_node.    For now I have tied by map and odom frames to be always the same, so I assume that GPS is giving absolute map positions, and report them in the map frame.   I am confused about the IMU though:    it's heading estimate should be in the map frame as it's absolute, but it's motion estimates should be in the base_link frame because they are relative to the robot.    The imu message only has a single frame_id, so which should I set it to?    Or do I perhaps need to send two copies of the imu message with two different frames there, and set up ekf_localization_node to only attend to the relevant measurements in each?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217415/ekf_localization_node:-what-frame-for-imu?/) by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2015-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah, you've stumbled upon the ol' "in what frame is IMU data reported" issue. See these:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/50870/what-frame-is-sensor_msgsimuorientation-relative-to/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/200480/imu-message-definition/
- https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/95

In `ekf_localization_node`, I assume the `frame_id` in the message is the frame in which the sensor is mounted, so you should produce a *base_link*->*imu* transform (try using `static_transform_publisher`).

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) on 2015-09-11**:
Thanks Tom, good to hear that from the source!